# How do I tell Siri to show me pictures I took at a state park rather than pictures of the state park from the Web?

Tags: ios, photos.app, siri

I took some pictures up at a state park where I was camping. When I tell Siri, "Show me pictures from XYZ State Park", Siri performs a Bing image search. When I say "Show me pictures I took at XYZ State Park", the Photos app pulls up and displays nothing.

However, the photos come up when I ask for photos I took within the state.

Comment: You could try asking for the photos you took at the park, but by requesting the date of the photo.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested on my iPhone when I tried searching for photos that I snapped at the Brooklyn Bridge Park by asking Siri "Search photos for Brooklyn Bridge Park" and it opened the photos app and filtered out showing me only those photos.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the location data for your state park pictures doesn't contain the name of the place but just your geographical location. This could be because you didn't have access to the internet at the park so iOS could not retrieve a name for your location, and instead relied on GPS to get your geographical location (which is why asking Siri for pictures from the state works).

To modify the location of a photo to include "XYZ State Park", you can view and edit location data in the Photos app on OS X ([tutorial on osxdaily.com](http://osxdaily.com/2015/11/06/add-location-to-pictures-photos-mac/)).

Comment: When I go to the Photos app manually, the pictures/videos I took at the state park appear under "XYZ State Park".